# Semantic ui search dropdown not updating the v-model on vue js

Tags: vuejs2, semantic-ui

everything works fine if i remove the class .search on my code.

```
<select class="ui dropdown" v-model="testimonials.category_id">
      <option disabled value="">Please select category</option>
      <option v-for="category in categories" :value="category.id">{{ category.title }}</option>
</select>
```

but when I bring back the .search class my v-model not updating every time I change the value.

heres my js on semantic:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
$('.ui.search.dropdown')
  .dropdown({
    maxSelections: 3
  });
});
```

Comment: Have you managed to solve the issue? Dealing with exact same thing at the moment.

Comment: no, but instead I used the [vue multiselect](https://vue-multiselect.js.org/)